# How to define a DEFAULT value for a CUSTOM datatype in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example *inside a package* there are two custom data types:

```
-- A single time period with start date and end date.
TYPE time_period IS OBJECT(
  start_period Datetime,
  end_period Datetime
);
-- A collection of defined time periods.
TYPE time_periods IS TABLE OF time_period;
```

How to define a default value for the second custom datatype inside the function parameter?

```
-- The main function.
FUNCTION Foo (bar_periods IN time_periods DEFAULT ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use type constructor, passing arguments of initial properties to it:

> ```
> create or replace package p_test as
>   TYPE time_period is record (
>     start_period Date,
>     end_period Date
>   );
>
>   TYPE time_periods IS TABLE OF time_period;
>
>   function f (
>     p in time_periods
>       default time_periods(
>         time_period(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-12-31'),
>         time_period(date '2020-01-01', date '2020-12-31')
>       )
>   ) return number;
> end;
> /
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9c77104c3b78464c0f63c5a7d85d082)*